# solve mysql query

Tags: mysql

Today I have been asked a question by an interviewer that stated 
we have three tables named as table A, B, and C.

Those tables are like this

```
       A                        B                             C
------------------  --------------------------   ----------------------------
| ID | ProjectID |  | ID | LocationID |  aID |   | ID | points | LocationID |
------------------  --------------------------   ----------------------------
| 1  |    15     |  | 1  |    131     |   1  |   | 1  | 123333 |     131    |
| 2  |    15     |  | 2  |    132     |   1  |   | 2  | 123223 |     132    |
| 3  |    15     |  | 3  |    133     |   1  |   | 3  | 522    |     211    |
| 4  |    12     |  | 4  |    134     |   2  |   | 4  | 25     |     136    |
------------------  | 5  |    136     |   2  |   | 5  | 25     |     133    |
                    | 6  |    137     |   3  |   | 6  | 25     |     134    |
                    | 7  |    138     |   1  |   | 7  | 25     |     135    |
                    --------------------------   ----------------------------
```

now he told me to write a query that sums the points of those locations whose project is 15.

First i wrote the query to get ID's from table A like this

```
SELECT ID from A where projectID  = 15
```

then i pass this result in table b query just like this

```
SELECT LocationID FROM B WHERE aID IN ( SELECT ID from A where projectID  = 15 )
```

Then i calculate the sum of these locations just like this

```
SELECT SUM(points) from C where LocationID IN(SELECT LocationID FROM B WHERE aID IN ( SELECT ID from A where projectID = 15))
```

My Result is fine and query is correct. But he rejected my answer by saying that this nested IN Clause will slow down the whole process as when we have thousands of records.
Then he gave me another chance to review my answer but i couldn't figure it out.

Is there anyway to optimize this or is there some other way to do the same.
Any help? Thanks

Comment: have you tried joins ?

Comment: You are writing 3 queries when you could write one using joins.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can an SQL query return data from multiple tables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12475850/how-can-an-sql-query-return-data-from-multiple-tables)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this it may solve your problem.

```
Select SUM(C.points) FROM C JOIN B ON C.LocationID = B.LocationID JOIN A ON B.aID = A.ID where A.ProjectID = 15 GROUPBY A.ProjectID
```

Comment: i tried this but this goes into infinite loop as it keep saying processing, processing and processing.

Comment: Its not will give you 246631 as output in 0.0010 second on 0.0000 as i have checked in my system with the data you have provided. Please check at your end.

Comment: Yeah it was an error on my End. Thanks it worked for me. and also vamshi's answer. i voted up for both the answers but not accepted any as i can't. Thanks Again

Answer (score 1):

Try with this....i hope it will work

```
 select sum(c.points) as sum_points 
 from A a,B b,C c where 
 a.ID=b.aID and 
 b.LocationID=c.LocationID
 and a.projectID=15
```

Comment: Thanks! It works for me and also Manoj Sharma's answer. who's answer should i accept? very difficult for me

Comment: It's your wish which you feel simple you can accept that answer